# Cannot read property '0' of undefined - While reading xls file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, xlsx, sheetjs

I'm trying to read excel data in angular 7. Below is the code.

```js
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
arrayBuffer: any;
file: File;

incomingfile(event) {
  let files = event.target.files;
  this.file = files[0];
}

Upload() {
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
    var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
    var arr = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
    var bstr = arr.join("");
    var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
      type: "binary"
    });
    var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
    console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
      raw: true
    }));
  }

  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
}
```

Below is the error:

> core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at parse_xlml_xml (xlsx.js:15669)
>       at parse_xlml (xlsx.js:16052)
>       at Object.readSync [as read] (xlsx.js:20413)
>       at FileReader.fileReader.onload (app.component.ts:40)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:161)
>       at FileReader. (zone.js:144)

I saved a simple excel file with 3 rows and 3 columns. Excel file with .xls extension (excel 97-2003) workshhet and Excel Workbook ()*.xlsx . Both of them don't seem to work.
Please let me know if i'm missing anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log(workbook.SheetNames)`?

Comment: I tried to print Sheet names, even before that it shows the error. If i change type from `binary` to  `array` it prints the sheet name but prints empty array.

Comment: Here is my stackblitz link  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybdrcg

Comment: The stackblitz is Working! it show me two objects in the console

Comment: You can share the sample excel, I think the problem is in Excel file

Comment: The file is corrupted! unable to open it in Excel 2007

Comment: I think I got it working. It was the file, it was corrupted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Most welcome..!